# Trying to populate NSMutableArray but get implicit conversion of int to id is disallowed with arc

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am simply trying to add a series of numbers to an `NSMutableArray` but I am getting the error:

*implicit conversion of int to id is disallowed with arc*

```
resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
[resultArray addObject:i];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` can only hold objects, not primitive data types such as `int`s. So if you want to add them to the array, you'll have to wrap them in an `NSNumber`. You can do the following:

```
[resultArray addObject:@(i)];
```

This is equivalent to doing:

```
[resultArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
```

Comment: @RichardGriffiths Yep, no problem. Just remember when you take them out of the array that they're objects, not primitive integer values, so you'll need to call either `intValue` or `integerValue` on the objects as you take them out if you want to get back to an `int` or `NSInteger`, respectively.